# Launch an activty from the browser by clicking a webpage link

Tags: android

I need to make an android App that when the user navigates to my webpage with the browser and clicks on a specific link my App activity gets launched.

I try to achieve this using Intent filters but without success. I followed some samples like Notepad and PhotoStream but nothing works for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch custom android application from android browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered in detail at

[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Hope it solves your problem.

Thanks,
-A